# What can cause a joinable thread to fail when calling join

Tags: c++, multithreading, std-system-error

When I call joinThread I occasionally get an `std::system_error` thrown of with "invalid argument" at the join call. The error appears to only show up when I compile with gcc, and it is not consistently reproducible, i.e. it occasionally occurs and not predictably. Does anyone know what could cause such an error?

Below is a reduced version of my code.

```
class exampleClass
{
   public:
   exampleClass()
   {
   }
   
   ~exampleClass()
   {
      joinThread();
   }

   void doWork()
   {
       joinThread();
       workThread = std::thread(&exampleClass::threadFunction, this);
   }

   void joinThread()
   {
      if(workThread.joinable()) workThread.join();
   }

   protected:
   void threadFunction()
   {
      std::cout << "Do something that requires time..." << std::endl
   }

   std::thread       workThread;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you written a small tester with this reduced version, which can reproduce this? With a main etc. so we have more context to analyze.

Comment: Ok I shall do so, I'm not sure the smaller program will as it comes from a fairly complex program. In theory though, there is nothing incorrect with the above correct?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong and I would assume you may have an error somewhere else. For the answer to your question: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join 
But the example is fairly easy. If you don't detach or move the thread object somewhere else in the code join should never faile after `joinable` was true (assuming you don't join in multiple threads on the same object)

Comment: I do have multiple threads on the real code (each running their own function), but they are never moved. Each thread is joined to the main thread sqeuentially, could that somehow cause a failure?l

Comment: In theory not. But the issue is probably in some details. We can help more if you have a reduced example which can reproduce it.

Comment: I could not reproduce the result in a simpler example, and somehow inserting the join call into a try statement stopped it from throwing. I guess there must have been some weird timing or compiler issue.

Comment: Most likely timing and not compiler issue. This still seems like your code is not working like it should and now it only works "by accident"

Comment: Not every routine/function/method/operator/keyword has a tag. Please choose tags from a list & read their wikis. Tag [tag:join] is for the relational DB operator.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not provide an example, where this error occurs, I can only speak from my own experience. There are some things you should consider, in order to avoid such an error:

- Is your thread just default constructed, resp. did you initialize it with a valid callback function?
- Is your thread detached?
- Have you `move`d your thread?
- Is the thread trying to access an already reserved resource? Think about possible deadlock sources! Maybe you got stuck somewhere. (But afaik the thread should still be joinable anyway.)
- Does a `friend` method or class try to access/use/join the thread?

I recently forgot to pass a function to a thread, which I had default constructed in order to use it later. This happened due to a conditional initialization procedure. So regarding your example class above:
Your `workThread` is default constructed upon constructing an object of `exampleClass`. A callback function is only passed, if you call `doWork()`. You have made sure that the thread is only joined, if it is in a joinable state. Upon destruction of your object this is also guaranteed. Thus, the most likely reason I can think of, why this might fail, is if you have somewhere a `friend`. You haven't put that in your example though, but maybe you neglected this, because you wanted to present a reduced form.

Maybe also a look here: http://cppatomic.blogspot.com/2018/05/modern-effective-c-make-stdthread.html might help.